# different colours in NSAttributedStrings are not applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

Here is my code:

```
 UIColor *_black=[UIColor blackColor];
 UIColor *_white=[UIColor whiteColor];
 [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, _commLen)];
 [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_white range:NSMakeRange(_commLen+1, _usrLen)];
cell.textLabel.attributedText = attString;
```

The lengths are correct and _commLen is 6 and _usrLen is 7.

So I expect from character 0 to 6 to be black, and from 7 to 13 to be white.

But I see only black.

What am I missing?

If I have this:

```
NSLOg(@"String:%@",attString);
```

then the output is this:

```
String = test -{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
} {
}string1{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
}
```

where `test -` should be black and `string1` white

Comment: Are you assigning the textLabel.text as well somewhere later on in the method?

Comment: @Stavash no there isn't any other assignment

Comment: What's the output of `NSLog(@"attrString = %@", attrString);` just before your assign `attrString` to the label?

Comment: What does the label actually look like at runtime?

Comment: @rmaddy it's only black, I cannot see the white colour

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: The attributed text looks correct. What method is the posted code from? `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Colors tend to get reset. Try doing this in the `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath` method and see if that helps.

Comment: @rmaddy can you give me an example? I haven't used that before and I always used cellForRowAtIndexPath. Should I live cellForRow or remove code completely from there? Which is called first?

Comment: Leave what you have. Just as a test, duplicate the code to set the cell's attributed label in the `willDisplayCell...` method. See the docs on that method for details.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, tried that but it does not work. I can still see only the black.

Comment: Can we show more of you code? According to the NSLog, the color effect is applied. So the issue is on showing.